# Google Maps iframe browser not displaying

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

Years ago this type of thing worked just fine.  This doesn't work in Chrome / FF  but in IE at least I get a warning about content not displayed, and I can spawn it in a new IE windows which displays the map.   I'm confused on why the standard bootstrap css and iframe with google map is not displaying.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- Google maps -->
                <div class="gmap">
                    <!-- Google Maps. Replace the below iframe with your Google Maps embed code -->
                    <iframe height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Acton,+MA&hl=en&sll=42.036922,-71.683501&sspn=2.647686,3.532104&oq=Acton&hnear=Acton,+Middlesex,+Massachusetts&t=m&z=12"></iframe>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a correct embed-code as provided by google Maps.

There is the parameter **`output=embed`** missing in the URL

Without this parameter the frame will be redirected to the new google Maps, where no
appropriate  **`X-Frame-Options`** -header will be sent (what prevents the browser from displaying the iframe)

Comment: Yes  adding this to end of url   &output=embed  Thanks!